# How to run custom code(hooks) after user signup on Paid Memberships Pro

Tags: php, wordpress

i want to execute a custom code after user signup on Paid Memberships PRO
and this looks like a solution

```
http://www.paidmembershipspro.com/hooks-filters/
```

"pmpro_after_checkout" looks exactly what i am looking for, but how do i execute it? where to write the custom code???
should i write this function in my theme's function.php file??

will it be a right approach if i write a new function in functions.php
for example in the sample code here "http://www.paidmembershipspro.com/hook/pmpro_after_checkout/"
i write a new function

```
function my_pmpro_after_checkout($user_id){
    //my custom code here
}
```

and call it in this location
wp-content/paid-memberships-pro/preheaders/checkout.php
line# 929
where another one is already called:

```
 //hook
 do_action("pmpro_after_checkout", $user_id);
```

and can i call my own function like this?

```
do_action("my_pmpro_after_checkout", $user_id);
```

i apologize if i didnt understand it... any help would be appreciated

Comment: you can try it with your theme functions.php

Answer (score 5):

Add this code in your theme functions.php or create a plugin and add there in plugins file:

```
add_action("pmpro_after_checkout", "update_user_meta_after_upgrade", 10 ,1 );

function update_user_meta_after_upgrade( $user_id ){
    // Get level details 
    $membership_level_details   = pmpro_getMembershipLevelsForUser($user_id);
    $level_id           = $membership_level_details[0]->ID;
// perform action according to the level    
return;
    }
```